# automatically append menu parent as first item in submenu with nav_walker

Tags: menus, navigation

In my navigation, items which have children should only be clickable to open / close the sub-menu. Because of this I'm searching for a way to append this item as first item in sub-menu so the page is accessible.

Here is a short example:

```
# structure in backend # needed in frontend                  #
# -------------------- # ----------------------------------- #
# item 1               # item 1                              #
# item 2               # item 2 (opens / closes submenu)     #
# - subitem 1          # - item 2 copy (normal link to page) #
# - subitem 2          # - subitem 1                         #
# - subitem 3          # - subitem 2                         #
# item 3               # - subitem 3                         #
#                      # item 3                              #
# -------------------- # ----------------------------------- #
```

I've tried it in the following way, with a count var, I know if I'm in a sub-menu and when it is the first item. So with the $item->object_id I could get all values from the parent menu-item. But I don't know how to create a new menu-item in the class method:

```
class flexnav_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    static $count=0;

    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

      $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

      $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
      $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

      $args = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_args', $args, $item, $depth );

      $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );
      $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

      $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
      $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

      $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names .'>';

      $atts = array();
      $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
      $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
      $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';

      $navActive = get_post_meta( $item->object_id, '_wecOverviewNavState', true );

      // remove link from pages with children
      if (in_array('menu-item-has-children', $classes, true)) {
          $atts['href'] = '#';
      }else{
          $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
      }

      $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

      $attributes = '';
      foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
        if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
          $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
          $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
        }
      }

      if ($depth==0) self::$count=0;  // reset var when we are in first level

        if ($depth==1 && self::$count==1) {  // if we are in submenu and items count is 1...

            // create a link from the actual parent
            // $hasChildren = count(get_pages(array( 'child_of' => $item->object_id )));

        }

      $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
      $title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $item, $args, $depth );

      $item_output = $args->before;
      $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
      $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
      $item_output .= '</a>';
      $item_output .= $args->after;

      $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );

      self::$count++;
    }

  }
```

Thanks for your help!